# How to populate second struts2 select tag based on value selected from first select tag?

Tags: java, select, struts2, dropdown, populate

I want to populate 3 selects (Zone, Station, Department) in struts2. 
Each dropdown displays various options depending on value(s) selected in previous dropdown:

1. First field is Zone. User will select single Zone from zone select.
2. Based on this selected zone, station select will get populated from database.
   User may select **multiple** stations here.
3. Based on these selected station(s), departments select tag will be populated from database.
   Users may select **multiple** departments here.

I am able to populate zone select(dropdown) on page load and display it to jsp page.
However, station select is not displayed on my page, even though `stationList` attribute gets populated from database. 
Setting it manually also does not help.

JSP Code here :

```
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" class="headingLabelStyle1" align="right">
        <s:label value="Zone" ></s:label></td>
    <td width="4%" align="center" class="headingLabelStyle1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:label value=":" /> </td>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:select name="pmrkpr8800Bean.zone" list="zoneList" id="zone" 
            headerValue="-- Please Select --" headerKey="-1" 
            tabindex="1" cssClass="h1"></s:select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" class="headingLabelStyle1" align="right">
        <s:label name="stncd"  value="Station Code" ></s:label></td>
    <td width="4%" align="center" class="headingLabelStyle1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:label value=":" /> </td>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:select name="pmrkpr8800Bean.stnCde" list="stationList" id="stnCde" headerValue="-- Please Select --" headerKey="-2" tabindex="2" cssClass="h1" size="3" multiple="true"></s:select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" class="headingLabelStyle1" align="right">
        <s:label value="Department" ></s:label></td>
    <td width="4%" align="center" class="headingLabelStyle1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:label value=":" /> </td>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <s:select name="pmrkpr8800Bean.dept" list="deptList" id="dept" headerValue="-- Please Select --" headerKey="-1" tabindex="3" cssClass="h1" size="3" multiple="true"></s:select>
    </td>                  
</tr>

public String populateZoneSelect() {
    String result = SUCCESS;
    try {
        log.info("Inside populateZoneSelect");
        zoneList = ipmrkpr8800.getZoneList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public String populateStationSelect() {
    String result = SUCCESS;
    String selZone = request.getParameter("selZone");
    System.out.println("Selected zone: " + selZone);

    try {
        stationList.put("CSMT", "CSMT-MUMBAI");
        stationList.put("NDL", "NDL-NEW DELHI");
        stationList.put("PNVL", "PNVL-PANVEL");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*try {
        log.info("Inside populateStationSelect");
        stationList = ipmrkpr8800.getStationList(selZone);
        System.out.println("StationList: " + stationList.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    return result;
}
```

Last two code blocks are from Action class. populateZoneList works fine and I am able to display different zones from database. Selected value is captured and sent to populateStationSelect(). if the commented part in the function is uncommented, stationList Map variable contains list of station codes and names.

But after that in jsp, in Station select tag only "Please Select" header value is displayed. The station codes and names retrireved from database are not displayed. 
I have written getters and setters for these map variables also in action.

Comment: I cannot understand what exactly you want to achieve, could you edit your question in a more clear way?

Comment: How are you currently trying to populate this 3rd select box after selections are made; page refresh, ajax?